# finding greatest differential in pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe below:

```
df 

    Ticker       Price     Volume        Price2
0        A  147.779999    51918.0  147.779999
1      AAL   21.209999   229944.0   44.523753
2      AAP  205.139999    32928.0   61.324705
3     AAPL  136.919998  1175723.0  120.954594
4     ABBV  112.599998   135235.0  120.259632
...
```

I want to parse through the df and find the Ticker that has the greatest differential between Price2 and Price (Price2 minus Price). Whatever Ticker is selected I want the value of the row to be stored in a variable so I can access the specific columns.

Is this possible? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can:

```py
differential = df['Price2'] - df['Price']
ticker = df.loc[differential.idxmax(), 'Ticker']
```

But seeing that you are working with stock prices, absolute price differential has little meaning. A $10 differential means more to a $136 stock (like Apple) than to a $3400 stock (like Amazon) and it's a rounding error on a $418k stock (Berkshire Hathaway). A better measure is to use differential percentage:

```py
differential = df['Price2'] / df['Price'] - 1
ticker = df.loc[differential.idxmax(), 'Ticker']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with `idxmax`

```
idx = (df['Price2'] - df['Price']).idxmax()
df.loc[idx]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s=df.iloc[abs(df['Price2'].sub(df['Price'])).idxmax(),:]#To acess all columns
```

or

```
s=df.loc[abs(df['Price2'].sub(df['Price'])).idxmax(),['Price2','Price']] #to access Price2 and Price
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# sample df
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.default_rng().integers(0, 100, size=(100, 2)), columns=['one', 'two'])

# create column with difference (two - one)
df['dif'] = abs(df['two'] - df['one'])

# get max difference index
print(df['dif'].idxmax()) # can store in a variable as well
```